# Name for flexible view-based layout like in Photoshop, Eclipse, Blender?

Tags: interaction-design, layout, design-patterns, view

Is there an established name for the visualization and interaction based on movable views as in Photoshop, Eclipse, Blender, etc.?

I refer to:

- a screen with some global controls
- onto which a set of views can be distributed (mostly, tiled, non-overlapping)
- views are connected, e.g., selection in one determines content in another
- views show different aspects of one (complex) model (such as a development project)
- where the user determines which views are shown
- views can be resized and dragged to their new place
- which allows to save a certain layout (as a "perspective" - Eclipse terminology)
- sometimes views can be combined into a tabbar, so only one of a few is visible at any time
- sometimes views can be torn off into their own window (possibly on another screen)

So it's not a term for a single control, but rather a "floorplan" of an entire app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between the patterns you list, and the overall environment.

From my understanding, there's a term for full screen, feature rich, highly configurable, immersive software applications (the floorplan):

**Sovereign posture applications**

Alan Cooper defines this in his book **[About Face](https://fall14se.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/about_face_3__the_essentials_of_interaction_design.pdf)**:

> Sovereign applications offer a large set of related functions
>   and features, and users tend to keep them up and running continuously, occupying
>   the full screen.
>
> No other application will be competing with yours, so don’t waste
>   space, but don’t be shy about taking what you need to do the job. If you need four
>   toolbars to cover the bases, use four toolbars. In an application of a different
>   posture, four toolbars may be overly complex, but the sovereign posture has a
>   defensible claim on the pixels.

For the features you outline, these are design patterns that are typically found within this application posture.

See the book **[Designing Interfaces](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082WQ28FM)** for more in-depth discussion of those particular patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop and Blender are examples of advanced [direct manipulation interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_manipulation_interface):

> the intention of direct manipulation is to allow a user to manipulate
>   objects presented to them, using actions that correspond at least
>   loosely to manipulation of physical objects. An example of direct
>   manipulation is resizing a graphical shape, such as a rectangle, by
>   dragging its corners or edges with a mouse

In Photoshop specifically, the central view where the user actually makes the flexible interactions that you are referring to is called the "canvas". You can manipulate the canvas in many ways, add to it, expand it, duplicate it, hide it, etc.